# migrate website to new folder. htaccess modify

Tags: .htaccess, url, migration, url-routing

I have on my domain abcdef.it a wordpress installation.
I installed a new version of my wordpress website to the folder newfolder.
Now I want that if I type the URL: ***www.abcdef.it***, browser show me the ***newfolder*** content, not showing up the name of root directory ***newfolder***

So the rules has to be:

1. www.abcdef.it => www.abcdef.it/newfolder content, but in the address bar I would read only www.abcdef.it
2. www.abcdef.it/newfolder => www.abcdef.it on the address bar
3. www.abcdef.it/newfolder/blog => www.abcdef.it/blog on the address bar

How I have to modify mi .htaccess file? Thanks a lot.